# Как правильно использовать преимущества ООП в данной ситуации?

Tags: c++, наследование, полиморфизм

Есть абстрактный класс `Capture` (для захвата изображений) c одним виртуальным методом `virtual size_t Grab(byte *frame) = 0;`. У него два наследника - `Screen` и `Camera`, которые по-своему реализуют `Grab`. При этом у `Screen` реализутся только захват, тогда как у камеры есть ещё свои методы, которых нет ни у экрана, ни у абстрактного родителя (кстати, правильно ли так делать?)

Вопрос в том как правильно сделать, чтобы не было ошибки компиляции при подобном вызове:

```
Capture *device = new Camera();
Camera->Start(); // метода Start нет у родителя, но есть у камеры.
```

Неужели нет лаконичного решения, кроме как прописать все возможные методы потомков у абстрактного родителя (а также их базовую реализацию у других потомков, которым эти методы не нужны, чисто для предотвращения ошибок)? Это простой пример, а есть ведь огромные "деревья" наследований - не прописывают же там все методы у всех "участников" процесса...

Comment: Тут либо вы максимизируете интерфейс базового класса, либо отказываетесь от общего наследника для `Screen` и `Camera` - по моему лучше второе, так как это уж слишком разные устройства

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, хорошо, но всё же, если взять более сложный пример с большим количеством наследований - не прописывать же всё в базе + реализации у потомков методов, которые они по логике не должны "уметь" вообще? Просто хочу окончательно разобраться как это правильно делается

Comment: Просто заведите ещё один абстрактный класс, описывающий процесс работы с Camera (start, stop, pause, что там ещё у вас), и наследуйте ваш класс Camera от него и от Capture. Так как с одной стороны видео камера и видео писать умеет, и изображение захватывать. А ещё фото наверное умеет делать.

Comment: Ну и вообще интерфейсы ж для чего - чтоб вот есть у вас ICapture - вы пишете функцию, принимающую этот `ICapture*`, а что там на самом деле отдастся - не важно (Screen или Camera), главное что вы можете сделать dynamic_cast<ICapture*>(...) от указателя на объект, и получите nullptr, если объект нельзя привести к этому интерфейсу. Всё

Comment: А в примере получается у вас есть объект ICapture, и вы хотите у него вызвать метод, которого у интерфейса ICapture нет. Я вот этого не понимаю. Почему не `auto camera = dynamic_cast<ICamera*>(device); if (camera){camera->Start();}`

Comment: @vegorov, ну, потому, что есть структура, которая объединяет различные параметры, объекты для работы с сетью для стрима... и одно из полей как раз устройство захвата. Структура передаётся в поток который реализует постоянное получение кадров из источника Capture и передачу их в стрим-менеджер... Работает параллельно 2 экземпляра потока, где используются одни и теже методы источников захвата, но остальные методы камеры также используются в других частях программы... Запуск, перевороты, остановка и тд. Хочется сделать красиво... )

Comment: И вам по-прежнему никто не мешает сделать ещё один интерфейс, описывающий поведение камеры.

Comment: @vegorov, идею понял, спасибо!

Comment: всегда есть решение лучше, но  окончательное решение зависит от  абстракции  и предназначения каждого в иерархии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала я бы сделал так:

```
struct Device {
    virtual bool start();
    virtual size_t grab(byte*) = 0;
    virtual void  off();
    //другие функции, свойственные этим устройствам
    // объекты для работы с сетью для стрима и т.д.
};
class Capture {/*...*/ };

class Camera :  public Device {
    std::unique_ptr<Capture> pc; 
public:
    Camera() : pc(nullptr) {}  // захват только по желанию пользователья
    bool start() override {/*...*/}
    size_t grab(byte* frame) final
    {/*может быть вызван например pс->grab()...*/ }
    void off()  override {/*...*/ }
    //другие функции, нуждающими в переопределении
    //другие функции для абстракции только камеры
};

class Screen :  public Device {
    std::unique_ptr<Capture> ps;
public:
    Screen() : ps(nullptr) {} // захват только по желанию пользователья     
    size_t grab(byte* frame) final
    {/*может быть вызван например ps->grab() */ }
    //другие функции для абстрации только экрана
};

void process(Device& pd, byte* f) {
    pd.start();
    pd.grab(f);
    pd.off();
}
```

**Что это значит?...**

И камера и экран являются устройсвами, которые могут захватить изображение, могут и не захватывать. А также устройство может по своему стартовать и выключаться, но камера может это делать так, как определено в базовом классе. Если я не ошибаюсь, вы этого хотели?

Comment: Да, выглядит логично, буду реализовывать. Спасибо